# Indenting by spaces using HTMLTidy in Notepad++

Tags: html, tabs, notepad++, tidy, indentation

How do I make it so that instead of indenting my elements by multiples of 2 spaces (when formatting without wrapping is selected), HTMLTidy indents them by multiples of tabs (4 spaces long but only 1 byte in size)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [HTML Tidy docs](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#tab-size) say that tidy never outputs tabs. But, since you're in Notepad++, you can use `TextFX Edit -> Leading space to tabs` to convert the spaces that HTMLTidy gives you into tabs. Just make sure that `indent-spaces` is set to `4` in your config file.

The location of your config file will vary depending on how you installed notepad++ and what version you have, but its path will probably look like one of these

```
C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\NPPTextFX\tidycfg.ini
C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\Config\tidy\tidycfg.ini
```

Comment: I think this worked. I didn't have to change any configuration files. But just in case, the configuration file you are talking about, is it the same one the above poster is talking about? I did manage to find that file. Thank you very much for the quick answer.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the same file as the other poster, but it looks like he deleted his post. I edited my post to include the path to the file.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you very much for the answers. They were very clear. Thank you so much.